# Angular-CLI (ng build --prod) fails with external local package

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot

I'm having one local package built (similar to npm package) and put it inside 'src/assets/external_js/test' directory **(not in node_modules)**. and used it as below:

```
import { TestModule } from 'assets/external_js/test'
```

I am able to run my application using `ng serve`, also able to build using `ng build --prod --aot=false`, but getting error with `--aot=true` or `(ng build --prod)`.

Getting below error.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve /home/demo/src/$$_gendir/assets/external_js/test/test.module.ngFactory in '/home/demo/src'

Also this runs perfectly, (able to build using --aot=true) if i put my local package 'Test' in node_modules directory but not working, if i put it outside node_modules directory.

Can anyone help me out, what i'm missing. Or how can i build my project with --aot=true.

Comment: i think it is down to the relate path of the module and cli is not able to resolve the path

Answer (score 0):

This is because in aot=true, it is compiling your application ahead of time.So it needs every dependency (viz. your test module) in advance i.e. at build time.
For complete reference of AOT compilation: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler